# Ruby on Rails - devise - User has :email field after removing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

GDPR compliance is a must have for my application. The only sensible data that I need to keep are email adresses, so I used https://github.com/ziptofaf/gdpr-rails as my base.

However, in my Rails console after -> `User.connection -> User -> It results in this User(id: integer, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, username: string, encrypted_email: string, encrypted_email_iv: string, avatar_file_name: string, avatar_content_type: string, avatar_file_size: integer, avatar_updated_at: datetime, email: )` it keeps saying that I have a email field. I checked my database tables and a email table doesn't exist.

The base comes with a bunch of methods and I want to provide my Users a way to export the data that I keep of them.

```
  <%= JSON.parse(User.export_personal_information_from_model(@user.id))%>
```

This results in seeing my acutal email unencrypted within the :email field from above. If I check this explicit User via Rails console the :email field says `email: nil`

```
{"id"=>3, "created_at"=>"2018-07-26T21:22:22.763+02:00", "updated_at"=>"2018-07-26T21:22:22.242+02:00", "username"=>"username", "encrypted_email"=>"somerandomstring=\n", "encrypted_email_iv"=>"somerandomstring\n", "avatar_file_name"=>nil, "avatar_content_type"=>nil, "avatar_file_size"=>nil, "avatar_updated_at"=>nil, "email"=>"some@email.com"}
```

Update:

Migration to remove column from users

```
class RemoveEmailFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_column :users, :email, :string
  end
end
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Devise? If so, your email field could come from there, if you deleted it, how did you do it? Try rake db:migrate you can also try reloading your rails console or restarting it.

Comment: could also have something to do with `attr_encrypted :email` as that gem will add `:email` as an attribute of the `ActiveRecord` instance. [Source](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/blob/master/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb#L50)

Comment: Yes, I am using devise. Deleted via Migration. Will add that to the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"I checked my database tables and a email table doesn't exist."*? Do you mean to say that you checked the **schema**, and an email **column** doesn't exist? (How did you check the database schema?)

Comment: (And have you definitely *run* that migration? I.e. `rake db:migrate`?)

Comment: I use Postgres as my main database and looked up my user model and it's columns via pgadmin.

Comment: Yes, I definitly run the migration.

Comment: What is the result of `User.columns`? What is the result of `User.first.method(:email).source_location`?

Comment: At the top of your question, you said that calling `User` from the rails console prints `avatar_updated_at: datetime,.... email: )` -- Is that information actually correct?! The `email` is ... **nothing**?! This shouldn't be a valid response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176836/discussion-between-benl96-and-tom-lord).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After discussion in the chat...)

There *isn't* an email column, but there *is* an email **attribute** on the model. This is [by design](https://github.com/ziptofaf/gdpr-rails/blob/ed31fe23bdd21ffcb76da42e023e57844aaadf98/app/models/user.rb#L12).

The GDPR-Rails gem works by defining columns named: `encrypted_email` and `encrypted_email_iv`, which store the *encrypted* email and the encryption *key*.

Then, when you call `user.email`, it uses this information to **decrypt** the email address.

Calling `User.export_personal_information_from_model(@user.id)` generates JSON of the record's attributes - which (again, by design) includes the *decrypted* email address.

So, tl;dr: Everything was working as it should, there was just a misunderstanding about the data being stored as encrypted.